# Can I detach/move a DB by just stopping the site rather than fully shutting down IIS on the WS

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, content-database, server-farm, database-attach

On my SharePoint 2010 Farm and Web Server. I have a number of Different sites.
Prod SharePoint, MySite, a separate ContentType Hub, and an attached DB of a 2007 Site.

I want to move the Content DB of the attached 2007 Site to another drive on the SQL Server through a Detach/Attach process. This site is just for old archived data and is rarely access (Mainly for Audit).

To start the detach, do I have to shut down all IIS services on my SP web server, or can I just stop the 'Site' under the IIS Manager, without affecting the rest of production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the database to read-only mode and that should be enough. No need to stop IIS site.

**UPDATE**

To set the database readonly using SQL Query use:

```
ALTER DATABASE DBName SET READ_ONLY
```

Same task can be performed by selecting the database in SQL management studio. Right click on the database, select properties, then select options, scroll down to State section and change Database Read-only prperty to true.